# After logout,how to redirect user to login page when he/she will click back button of browser in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-9

I am working on ASP.NET MVC3 project with C# and SQL SERVER 2008 as a backend.

Mu issue is:

On the Logout Controller am doing

```
Session.Abandon();

 HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie("Cookie-Name") { Value = string.Empty });
```

Due to this, session will be cleared and Cookie will also get cleared.

Now I want that if any user will click on Browser's Back button, he/she should be redirected to Login Page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

and use the `[Authorize]` data annotation on the required actions. You should be doing something like that for all your pages that require a user to be logged in anyway.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't satisfy my need. I am doing logout. after that it will be redirected to logout page. After this if user tries to click on back button of browser then only he/she should be redirected to login page

Comment: Then can you explain your need a little more? If pages require authorisation then an automatic redirect should do what you want. Good luck.